# GWT change chart options after drawn

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

Is it possible to change certain chart options for an already drawn chart (i.e. columnchart).

The general idea of what I'm trying to accomplish is, I created a widget that contains a chart, and after the chart is already drawn and displayed, I would like to for example be able to change the background of the chart when clicking on the widget, which in my case extends FocusPanel to be able to listen to clickevents (It contains more things than just the 1 chart)

I don't see any methods in columnchart to be able to either set the options, or get the options of this chart(to be able to just create a new chart with one option changed and keep the rest of them the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it is to redraw the chart with the updated Options. 
According to the google chart tools [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visdraw):

> draw()
>
> Draws the visualization on the page. Behind the scenes this can be
>   fetching a graphic from a server or creating the graphic on the page
>   using the linked visualization code. **You should call this method every
>   time the data or options change**. The object should be drawn inside the
>   DOM element passed into the constructor.
>
> draw(data[, options])

Comment: That's what I figured, but is there a way to actually get the options from a chart object (I don't see a way to do that), or do I have to keep track of the options separate somewhere, which I would prefer not to do unless it's the only way

Comment: `Option` and `DataTable` are unfortunstely private in the `Visualization` class. So you have too keep rack of them yourself.